# How to compare python objects which wrap pointers to existing C++ structures?

Tags: boost-python

I have a class method that returns a pointer to an inner data structure (where the data structure is guaranteed to outlive its use in python code). It looks like:

```
class MyClass {
    ...

    some_structure* get() {
        return inner_structure_;
    }

    private:
    some_structure* inner_structure_;
};
```

I want to wrap this `get()` method in Boost::Python so that if two different objects of this class return the same pointer, the associated `some_structure` objects in python compare equal.

Inside the `class_<MyClass>` definition I've tried wrapping `get()` with both `return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>()` and `return_inner_reference<>()` call policies, but in both cases, calling `get()` on different python "MyClass" objects returns different `some_structure` objects even though all point to the same memory address in C++.

How would I get around this? Might there be a hidden property inside the wrapper object that stores the pointer's address, so I can compare those instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it, although it still feels hackish and that there should be some easier way. But here goes:

1) Define your own methods that compare the pointers.

```
template <typename T>
bool eq(const T* self, const T* rhs) {                
  return self == rhs;                                                           
}                                                                               

template <typename T>                                                           
bool ne(const T* self, const T* rhs) {                
  return !eq<T>(self, rhs);                                              
}
```

2) Manually declare the `__eq__` and `__ne__` inside the wrapper class to point to those methods:

```
class_<smth>("smth", no_init)
  ...
  .def("__eq__", &eq<smth>)
  .def("__ne__", &ne<smth>);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the more convenient syntax for overloading as shown [in boost::python docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_operators_special_functions)? The comparator template still needed, though.

Comment: But there is not comparison in that link you posted...
I don't think Dan's solution is hackish at all, it feels really "pythonic" to me.